# histogram using gnuplot for multiple data in the same graph

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot two data series plotted in one graph (histogram) using gnuplot. One is Baseline data and other one is Optimized. The script looks like this currently.

```
 n=50
    max=0.07946462
    min=0.0
    reset
    width=(max-min)/n #interval width
    hist(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)+width/2.0 #function used to map a value 
    to the intervals
    set term png #output terminal and file
    set output "histogram.png"
    set xrange [min:max]
    set yrange [0:]
    set style fill solid 0.5 #fillstyle
    set termopt enhanced    # turn on enhanced text mode
    set xlabel "PowerDensity(mA/um2)"
    set ylabel "Area(um2)"
    set title 'Power Density Histogram'
    plot 'power_density_oxili_sptp.txt' u (hist($2,width)):($1) smooth frequency 
    w boxes lc rgb"blue" title 'Baseline', 'power_density_oxili_sptp.txt' u 
    (hist($3,width)):($1) smooth frequency w boxes lc rgb"red" title 'Optimized'
```

The output of this will be as given

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWhCv.jpg)

The problem here, I am not able to see baseline data (blue) completely,since it is hiding below the optimized data.Either I need to see both data or I need to plot histogram separately in the same graph.
Br
Sree

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the two histograms to be transparent. For that you should set the `transparent` flag in your fillstyle (see `help fillstyple`):

```
set style fill transparent solid 0.5
```

In addition, you need to specify `truecolor` to get transparent areas from the standard png terminal (see `help png`):

```
set term png truecolor
```

Alternatively you can use the `pngcairo` terminal.